# 100% Width Footer - Custom Child Theme

Tags: css, child-theme, footer

I am working on a custom child theme for Wordpress and I can not seem to get a footer width of 100% to be represented.

Live Example Page : http://glustik.com/wordpress/

I have tried multiple things, but I cant get the footer background to show up, the contents of the footer show up fine.

**Here is the Footer Code I am Using.**
*(I am trying to replicate the Header)*

```
#footer{
    width: 100%;
    margin:20px 0 20px 0;
    height:280px;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-top-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.14); 
    border-bottom-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
    border-left-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
    border-right-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
    display:block;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 15px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 15px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    background: #262626; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #262626 0%, #131313 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#262626), color-stop(100%,#131313)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #262626 0%,#131313 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #262626 0%,#131313 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #262626 0%,#131313 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(top,  #262626 0%,#131313 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#262626', endColorstr='#131313',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
```

**Here is the HTML for my FOOTER.php :**

```
    <div id="map">
        <iframe width="425" height="150" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://maps.google.com/maps?hl=en&amp;safe=off&amp;q=3945+S+Durango+Dr+Ste+A6+Las+Vegas,+NV+89147&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=3945+S+Durango+Dr,+Las+Vegas,+Nevada+89147&amp;gl=us&amp;t=m&amp;z=14&amp;ll=36.117592,-115.27902&amp;output=embed"></iframe>
    </div><!-- #map -->

   <div id="footerInfo">
        <p>
            <span class="bold">Address:</span><br />
            3945 S Durango Dr<br />
            Las Vegas, NV 89147<br /><br />

            <span class="bold">Phone:</span><br />
            702-349-0320<br /><br />

            <span class="bold">Hours:</span><br />
            11am - 3am
        </p>
    </div><!-- #footerInfo -->

    <div id="socialMedia">
        <p>
            Facebook, Twitter, Yelp, and Kyara go Here.
        </p>
    </div><!-- #socialMedia -->

    <div class="clearfix"></div>

    <div id="copyright">
        <p>Website Design by <a href="http://glustik.com">gluSTIK Multimedia</a></p>
    </div><!-- #copyright -->
</div><!-- .wrapper -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code, I don't see anything obviously wrong, but using Safari's inspector, it becomes clear that the footer DIV is not invoking the #footer CSS rule. Not clear why.

If the header div and footer div have the same styling, you can simplify your code by using one set of styles: #header, #footer {...}. Less to go wrong.

Comment: Hey that helped. Its showing up now. So I can work with this. Thanks for your Advice.